# Maven Project From Github To Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, odata

I am a beginner in maven

so, I am trying to create maven depend on progect in github 
I git this project https://github.com/jenshuesken/incubator-olingo-odata4

I need to use ODataJClient, I am trying to git clone and import it in eclipse 
but nothing come, please see figure 1

[figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFvPE.png)

I need to use engin in ODataJClient 
AM waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right step is build all modules in eclipse,then push it to github. A parent pom includes all modules information. After this,you can git clone it  correctly.

Comment: you mean create a fake maven project and take a parent pom and bulid then push it to github finally git clone

Comment: @TurkiBinTalib  build project in eclipse, copy you file into this project, make it a correct maven project without mistakes in eclipse,then push it to github. now because the structure of your maven project on github is correct, you will git clone it to your computer without error.